# Relation between raser and riezati

Tags: étymologie

Do the French verb raser have somehow relation with the Old Slavonic verb рѣзати (riezati) 'to cut', where the ати (ati) is a verb ending?

Answer (score 1):

Selon le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/raser) :

> Du lat. pop. *rasare, altér. (d'apr. le supin rasum) du class. radere « raser », « gratter, polir, ratisser » et « toucher en passant, effleurer, côtoyer ».

Answer (score 1):

All Slavic languages share the verb *rězati* which means *to cut*.

Their etymon is assumed to be **razЪ* which would come from **rōzo* but there is no agreement about its Indo-European origin, if any. Some authors suggest it is **u̯reĝ-*.

On the other hand, *raser* comes for the Latin *radere* which relates to the Indo-European  **reh₁d-*.

There is then no evidence of any link between these verbs.

References:

- HAL [Actualisation, intensité et saillance : raz mot autonome
  et préfixe en russe contemporain
  Olga Kravchenko-Biberson](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01529854/document)
- Wikipedia [raser](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/raser), [rado](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rado#la), [rodo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rodo#Etymology)

Comment: Your first PIE form looks a bit odd; you seem to have used non-combining forms of the diacritics (also the inverted breve has been displaced and the macron isn’t needed here since it’s just quoting a root, so full grade would be the norm). Try this instead: _*u̯reĝ-_. Similarly, the second root can just be written _*reh1d-_ (_*red-_ would be a different root, of which _*rōd-_ would be the lengthened o-grade).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks for the PIE spelling. The one I used was broken during a copy/paste  operation.